# What Are ABCD Prefixes Before Utility Network Package Asset Package

Tags: arcgis-pro, utility-network

Can you please let me know what are the What Are A,B,C, and D Prefixes before the Utility Network Package Asset Package?

I couldn't find any thing on esri documentation for the purpose of this naming convention

[image]

Answer (score 1):

_Version
Table used to store metadata about the asset package.

A_DomainNetwork
Table used to define the domain networks in a utility network.

B_AssociationRole
Table used to define the association roles for assembly and structure features.

B_AttributeIndex
Table used to define the attribute indexes in a utility network.

B_AttributeIndex_Fields
Table used to define the attribute indexes fields in a utility network.

B_AttributeRules
Table used to define the attribute rules for a utility network.

B_DatabaseSequence
Table used to maintain an enterprise database sequence.

B_DiagramTemplate
Table used to define the diagram templates for a utility network.

B_EdgeConnectivity
Table used to assign edge connectivity in a utility network.

B_NetworkAttribute
Table used to define network attributes in a utility network.

B_NetworkAttribute_Assignment
Table used to define the network attributes that are assigned in a utility network.

B_NetworkCategory
Table used to define categories in a utility network.

B_NetworkCategory_Assignments
Table used to assign categories to an asset type in the domain networks.

B_Rules
Table used to assign rules to a utility network.

B_Subnetwork_ConditionBarriers
Table used to define the condition barriers of subnetwork traces.

B_Subnetwork_Devices
Table used to define devices at an asset group/asset type combination that will be considered valid for a subnetwork.

B_Subnetwork_Diagrams
Table used to define the diagram template that will be used to generate subnetwork system diagrams for each subnetwork in a tier.

B_Subnetwork_EdgeObjects
Table used to define edge objects.

B_Subnetwork_FunctionBarriers
Table used to define the function barriers of subnetwork traces.

B_Subnetwork_JunctionObject
Table used to define junction objects.

B_Subnetwork_Junctions
Table used to define junctions.

B_Subnetwork_Lines
Table used to define lines at an asset group/asset type combination that will be considered valid lines in a subnetwork.

B_Subnetwork_Propagators
Table used to define network attributes to propagate.

B_Subnetwork_Summaries
Table used to define the summary attribute fields and properties to store function results when intersecting or updating subnet line features.

B_TerminalConfiguration
Table used to define terminal configurations in a utility network.

B_TerminalConfiguration_Assignment
Table used to define the terminal configurations that will be assigned to a device in a utility network.

B_TerminalConfiguration_Terminals
Table used to define the terminals for each terminal configuration.

B_TerminalConfiguration_ValidPaths
Table used to define the valid paths in a device that a commodity can travel for each terminal configuration.

B_Tier
Table used to define tiers.

B_TierGroup
Table used to define the tier groups in a subnetwork.

B_TraceConfigurations
Table used to define the trace configurations.

C_Associations
Table used to specify junction-junction connectivity, structural attachments, and containment associations for a utility network.

C_SubnetworkControllers
Table used to define the subnetwork controllers, which are locations where the subnetwork originates (sources) or terminates (sinks).

D_Configurations
Table used to define what properties are associated with different categories.

D_Rename
Table used to allow users to rename items in the asset package.

https://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/help/utility-network-automation/asset-package-reference/an-overview-of-the-asset-package.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `A` prefix is for the domain table describing which commodity, partitioned or hierarchical etc. These are high-level attributes assigned to the Utility Network itself.

The `B` prefix is for tables that set all of the schema up for the Utility Network. This is the first set of tables that the Apply Asset Package tool executes.

The `C` prefix is for tables that are applied at the very end of Apply Asset Package. These are for applying non-coincident associations between features and for applying which devices will be your subnetwork controllers for subnetwork management.

The `D` prefix is for tables that assist with fine-tuning and localizing your Utility Network.  The `D_configuration` tables remove unnecessary elements from the Utility Network that your utility may not need.  Example. Transmission vs Distribution only utilities. The `D_rename` table allows for a quick and easy method to rename alias's within your utility network to a different language or term. The `D` tables if present within an asset package will appear as a configuration drop-down during Apply Asset Package.